# How do I do a recursion over objects of unknown depth in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, playwright

I have a JSON file with a category structure of unknown depth. I want to make sure all pages can be accessed. I established three nested calls, but I think it would be better to recursion here. Unfortunately, I have no experience with Typescript regarding recursion. Can someone be so kind as to help me put the logic into a function I can call?

```
  test.setTimeout(28800000); // 8 hours max.
    // console.log(ofcJSON)
  for (let i = 0; i < ofcJSON.items.length; i++) {
    let currentPage = ofcJSON.items[i].link
    console.log(currentPage)
    if (!currentPage.startsWith("http")) await page.goto(currentPage)
    if (ofcJSON.items[i].items != null) {
        for (let j = 0; j < ofcJSON.items[i].items!.length; j++) {
            let currentPage1 = ofcJSON.items[i].items![j].link
            console.log(currentPage1)
            if (!currentPage1.startsWith("http")) await page.goto(currentPage1)
            if (ofcJSON.items[i].items![j].items != null) {
                for(let k = 0; k < ofcJSON.items[i].items![j].items!.length; k++) {
                    let currentPage2 = ofcJSON.items[i].items![j].items![k].link
                    console.log(currentPage2)
                    if (!currentPage2.startsWith("http")) await page.goto(currentPage2)
                    if (ofcJSON.items![i].items![j].items![k].items != null) {
                        for(let l = 0; l < ofcJSON.items[i].items![j].items![k].items!.length; l++) {
                            let currentPage3 = ofcJSON.items[i].items![j].items![k].items![l].link
                            console.log(currentPage3)
                            if (!currentPage3.startsWith("http")) await page.goto(currentPage3)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

The JSON has 1 **items** object, which in turn can have 1 **items** object. This is optional. I don't know the depth.

Answer (score 0):

I sketched an implementation which compiles and runs in the [typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nngdkm) as below (click on Run top left in the playground)...

```js
type HttpLink = `http{'s'|''}://${string}`;

function isHttpLink(link: string): link is HttpLink {
  return !!link.match(/^https?:\/\//);
}

type Link = HttpLink | string;

interface Item {
  link: Link;
  items?: Item[];
}

async function goto(link: HttpLink) {
  console.log(`Ran goto on ${link}`);
}

async function visitItemAndDescendants(ancestor: Item) {
  const { link, items } = ancestor;
  if (isHttpLink(link)) {
    await goto(link);
  }
  if (items) {
    for (const item of items) {
      visitItemAndDescendants(item);
    }
  }
}

{
  const exampleItem: Item = {
    link: "https://my.url",
    items: [
      {
        link: "not http",
        items: [
          {
            link:"http://insecure.url"
          },
          {
            link:"https://another.url"
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  visitItemAndDescendants(exampleItem)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the response data into the interface? I succeed in loading 7 parent items using the following code:
```const response = await fetch('https://myJSON').then((response) => response.json()).then((item) => { return item.items }); console.log(response.length);
```
But what now?

Comment: If there's some kind of reference you need back from each item, then passing down a list in the recursive call will probably work. Then after loading any item, you put the data you want in the list and by the time the recursion has completed, everything you want is in the list.

Comment: The original question seemed to suggest having it NOT throw an exception would be good enough to know that everything was valid, which is why there was no structure returned from the recursion in the example shared. I was assuming that `await page goto(link)` would throw if there was no such link, so even just completing the function call was indication enough that all links were valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your help and the help of a colleague I have solved the problem as follows:

```
import { Page, test } from '@playwright/test';
import fetch from "node-fetch";

test.use({
    baseURL: "https://www.myUrl.de/"
})

const links: string[] = [];

interface Item {

    link: string;
    items?: Item[];
}

async function getLinks(item: Item): Promise<void> {
    if (item.items && item.items.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < item.items.length; i++) {
            let currentItem = item.items[i];
            if (currentItem.link && currentItem.link.length > 0) {
                links.push(currentItem.link);
                if (currentItem.items && currentItem.items.length > 0)
                    getLinks(currentItem);
            }
        }
    }
}

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
    test.setTimeout(1560000); // 26 minutes max.

    const ofcJSON = await fetch('https://www.myUrl.de/ofcJSON')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((item) => {
            return item.items
        })

    // console.log(ofcJSON);

    ofcJSON.forEach(element => {
        getLinks(element);
    });

    var maximumNumberOfLinksToCheck = 10;
    var delta = Math.floor(links.length / maximumNumberOfLinksToCheck);

    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i = i + delta) {
        console.log("Checking page: " + links[i])
        await (page.goto(links[i]));
    }
});
```